# How to set HTML table column widths as a percentage (without table footer affecting table body)?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm really having a hard time understanding how to style column widths in a HTML table. I can't get my head around why percentage widths aren't applying and why columns inside `tfoot` affect column widths in tbody.

Can anyone shed some light on this and perhaps explain how I can make the columns within the `tbody` be set to one-third (33.333%) and columns in the `tfoot` be set to one-half (50%) and actually span the full width of the table (right now they only span across 2 columns above, rather than 3 columns)?

Any help/guidance would be most appreciated.

```css
tbody,
tfoot {
  width: 100%;
}

tbody tr td {
  width: 33.333%;
}

tfoot tr th, 
tfoot tr td {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Body Row 1 Column 1</td>
    <td>Body Row 1 Column 2</td>
    <td>Body Row 1 Column 3</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <th>Footer Row 1 Column 1</th>
    <td>Footer Row 1 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Footer Row 2 Column 1</th>
    <td>Footer Row 2 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Footer Row 3 Column 1</th>
    <td>Footer Row 3 Column 2</td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: well thats not how tables work, you would need like a colspan. are trying to do a layout in tables or just displaying data?

Comment: I'm simply trying to output table data but want to control the widths of the columns. How would colspan work in this instance?

Comment: Never mind, I think I've got it. I've been thinking about tables wrong and need to simplify them. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not restricted so that you *have* to use one table, why not just a table inside a table?

```html
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>First half</td>
            <td>Second half</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Just make sure the styling applies just as well and give your `table table { width: 100%; }`, no border, margin, padding, etc..
I find the best solutions are those where you ignore the problem.